# My Image Button Function is not working

Tags: java, android

I have here a code which gets the user's current location thru GPS and send to other via SMS. There are no errors in my code however it is not functioning/sending SMS.

my MainActivity.class

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageButton btnOneTap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOneTap);

btnOneTap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {        
        // create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            try {
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+639123456789", null, "I Need Help! Please Click the Link To Know My Location https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "", null, null);                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                dialog.show();
            }
        }else{
//               can't get location
//               GPS or Network is not enabled
//               Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }               
    }
});
```

my GPSTracker.class

```
import android.app.AlertDialog;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.DialogInterface;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.provider.Settings;
import android.util.Log;

public class GPSTracker extends Service implements LocationListener {

private final Context mContext;

// flag for GPS status
boolean isGPSEnabled = false;

// flag for network status
boolean isNetworkEnabled = false;

// flag for GPS status
boolean canGetLocation = false;

Location location; // location
double latitude; // latitude
double longitude; // longitude

// The minimum distance to change Updates in meters
private static final long MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES = 10; // 10 meters

// The minimum time between updates in milliseconds
private static final long MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES = 1000 * 60 * 1; // 1 minute

// Declaring a Location Manager
protected LocationManager locationManager;

public GPSTracker(Context context) {
    this.mContext = context;
    getLocation();
}

public Location getLocation() {
    try {
        locationManager = (LocationManager) mContext
                .getSystemService(LOCATION_SERVICE);

        // getting GPS status
        isGPSEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);

        // getting network status
        isNetworkEnabled = locationManager
                .isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);

        if (!isGPSEnabled && !isNetworkEnabled) {
            // no network provider is enabled
        } else {
            this.canGetLocation = true;
            if (isNetworkEnabled) {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                        LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER,
                        MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                        MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                Log.d("Network", "Network");
                if (locationManager != null) {
                    location = locationManager
                            .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.NETWORK_PROVIDER);
                    if (location != null) {
                        latitude = location.getLatitude();
                        longitude = location.getLongitude();
                    }
                }
            }
            // if GPS Enabled get lat/long using GPS Services
            if (isGPSEnabled) {
                if (location == null) {
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(
                            LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER,
                            MIN_TIME_BW_UPDATES,
                            MIN_DISTANCE_CHANGE_FOR_UPDATES, this);
                    Log.d("GPS Enabled", "GPS Enabled");
                    if (locationManager != null) {
                        location = locationManager
                                .getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                        if (location != null) {
                            latitude = location.getLatitude();
                            longitude = location.getLongitude();
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return location;
}

/**
 * Stop using GPS listener
 * Calling this function will stop using GPS in your app
 * */
public void stopUsingGPS(){
    if(locationManager != null){
        locationManager.removeUpdates(GPSTracker.this);
    }       
}

/**
 * Function to get latitude
 * */
public double getLatitude(){
    if(location != null){
        latitude = location.getLatitude();
    }

    // return latitude
    return latitude;
}

/**
 * Function to get longitude
 * */
public double getLongitude(){
    if(location != null){
        longitude = location.getLongitude();
    }

    // return longitude
    return longitude;
}

/**
 * Function to check GPS/wifi enabled
 * @return boolean
 * */
public boolean canGetLocation() {
    return this.canGetLocation;
}

/**
 * Function to show settings alert dialog
 * On pressing Settings button will lauch Settings Options
 * */
public void showSettingsAlert(){
    AlertDialog.Builder alertDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(mContext);

    // Setting Dialog Title
    alertDialog.setTitle("GPS is settings");

    // Setting Dialog Message
    alertDialog.setMessage("GPS is not enabled. Do you want to go to settings menu?");

    // On pressing Settings button
    alertDialog.setPositiveButton("Settings", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog,int which) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(Settings.ACTION_LOCATION_SOURCE_SETTINGS);
            mContext.startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

    // on pressing cancel button
    alertDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        dialog.cancel();
        }
    });

    // Showing Alert Message
    alertDialog.show();
}

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {
}

@Override
public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {
}

@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent arg0) {
    return null;
}

}
```

these codes works on a separate project but when i try to integrate/insert it on my project it is not working. any idea why?

Comment: @rajanks when i tried to post my logcat it says its too long.

Comment: Clear the logcat then run the app,you will be able to get only error details copy and paste that

Comment: yes i did that but its too many warnings.

Answer (score 0):

Initialize your gps OUTSIDE of your setOnClickListener. This way, their will be enough time for your gps tracker to get your locations.

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

    GPSTracker gps;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
ImageButton btnOneTap = (ImageButton) findViewById(R.id.btnOneTap);
// create class object
        gps = new GPSTracker(MainActivity.this);

btnOneTap.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View arg0) {        


        // check if GPS enabled     
        if(gps.canGetLocation()){

            double latitude = gps.getLatitude();
            double longitude = gps.getLongitude();

            try {
                SmsManager.getDefault().sendTextMessage("+639123456789", null, "I Need Help! Please Click the Link To Know My Location https://www.google.com/maps/?q=" + latitude + "," + longitude + "", null, null);                 
            } catch (Exception e) {
                AlertDialog.Builder alertDialogBuilder = new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this);
                AlertDialog dialog = alertDialogBuilder.create();
                dialog.setMessage(e.getMessage());
                dialog.show();
            }
        }else{
//               can't get location
//               GPS or Network is not enabled
//               Ask user to enable GPS/network in settings
            gps.showSettingsAlert();
        }               
    }
});
```